# Use css to display menu when hovering over an image

Tags: html, css

I am wanting the menu to display when the user however over the image. Currently, I am not seeing anything when I hover over the image.

```css
.locklear-brand {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
.locklear-brand img {
    width: 30px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.locklear-brand ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; 
}
.locklear-brand img:hover > ul {
    display: inherit;
}
.locklear-brand ul li {
    width:170px;
    float:none;
    display:list-item;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="locklear-brand">
  <img src="locklear.png">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Themes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Plugins</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are using the direct descendant selector `>` instead of the immediate sibling selector `+`. That is because the `<ul>` element is not a child of the `<img>` element, but rather a sibling of it.

Changing that will fix your problem: `.locklear-brand img:hover + ul`. See proof-of-concept below:

```css
.locklear-brand {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
.locklear-brand img {
    width: 30px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.locklear-brand ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; 
}
.locklear-brand img:hover + ul {
    display: inherit;
}
.locklear-brand ul li {
    width:170px;
    float:none;
    display:list-item;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="locklear-brand">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" />
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Themes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Plugins</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

A more relevant question is: how can you create a dropdown menu so that when the image is hovered, that the menu remains interactable. This means you want the entire `.locklear-brand` to receive the hover state, not just the image element:

```css
.locklear-brand {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
.locklear-brand img {
    width: 30px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.locklear-brand ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; 
    
    /* Ensure that mouse can move to <ul> without exiting parent */
    margin-top: 0;
}
.locklear-brand:hover ul {
    display: inherit;
}
.locklear-brand ul li {
    width:170px;
    float:none;
    display:list-item;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="locklear-brand">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" />
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Themes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Plugins</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: However, the menu is inaccessible!

Comment: @SaidbakR That is indeed a usability issue, but beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: @Lumbee If you want the menu to be truly interaction upon hover, I suggest you look at how dropdown menus are implemented using pure CSS: https://css-tricks.com/solved-with-css-dropdown-menus/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following CSS to allow accessibility to the menu:

```
<style>
    .locklear-brand {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 50px;          
}
.locklear-brand img {
    width: 30px;
    padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.locklear-brand ul {
    display: none;
    position: relative;       
}
.locklear-brand:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    }
.locklear-brand ul li {
    width:170px;
    float:none;
    display:list-item;
    position: relative;
}    
  </style>
```

In other words, making the hover for the container `div` instead of the image.
Checkout this [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/sohepatoge/edit?html,output)

```css
.locklear-brand {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 50px;
      
}
.locklear-brand img {
    width: 30px;
    padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.locklear-brand ul {
    display: none;
    position: relative; 
  
}
.locklear-brand:hover > ul {
    display: block;  
    }
.locklear-brand:hover{
      border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  box-shadow: -6px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }
    
.locklear-brand ul li {
    width:170px;
    float:none;
    display:list-item;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="locklear-brand">
  <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Themes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Plugins</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```